# apache2 + MPM-ITK + PHP = socket doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, sockets

I have 2 servers running an proprietary software that I can access by an specific port and sending/receiving JSON string.
In both servers, I have apache2 with ITK for each virtual host.
In server "A", I have an PHP script that uses socket to connect to server "A" and "B" to get data and display on webpage. The problem is that PHP can connect only to server "A" (localhsot), but can't connect to server "B". The PHP doesn't show any error (display_errors are on in php.ini) and when I try to get last error from socket (I don't remember the php function right now), I get nothing.
On apache log, I got this error:

> Operation not permitted: AH02156: setgid: unable to set group id to
>   Group 0

There's no firewall blocking between hosts, I can 'telnet' both servers in any direction without any problem. Just PHP doesn't connect to 'external' hsot, just localhost.
The only change in my vhost file is to add itk option:

> AssignUserId rpi rpi

So my question is: how to I configure apache-itk to allow my PHP to open external sockets?
I have tried to change LimitUIDRange to "LimitUIDRange 0 0", but no success.

Answer (score 0):

maybe related to the Apache module:

> mpm_itk_module

or

> AssignUserId

Apache config.

Please see this links:

- http://forum.ispsystem.com/showthread.php?t=2917
- https://forum.root.cz/index.php?topic=15707.0

I'm trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: Please see too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/491624/setresuid-operation-not-permitted-when-calling-via-php

Answer (score 0):

If you set `LimitUIDRange 0 0`, that means that only root is allowed, which doesn't make sense. The correct directives would be `LimitUIDRange 0 65534` and `LimitGIDRange 0 65534`. As long as you don't set any hosts to be run as root, this is not any more insecure than default apache. Especialy does it not mean that website users are allowed to change their own user id. However, they will be allowed to run executables with the setuid bit set, like any other normal user.